# I am getting an IO exception when I am using android's geocoder and address library to convert address to long and lat. What did I do wrong?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, geocoding

I wrote a method to get the latitude and longitude from an address called `destination`. The String `destination` gets input like (1234 Jondoe Avenue Saratoga CA) and is supposed to output the longitude and latitude through SMS to my twilio number. It works and sends the number. It locates my present position in longitude and latitude, but it doesn't do that for my destination address. It doesn't convert it to longitude and latitude. Instead it throws an IOException. Could anyone give me any guidance or solution to my problem?

Here is my code:

```
public double latSM(String destination) throws IOException{
        double destLat1 = 0.0;
        double destLng1 = 0.0;


        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(destination, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        destLat1 = add.getLatitude();
        destLng1 = add.getLongitude();
        return destLat1;
    }
    public double lngSM(String destination) throws IOException{
        double destLat1 = 0.0;
        double destLng1 = 0.0;


        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(destination, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        destLat1 = add.getLatitude();
        destLng1 = add.getLongitude();
        return destLng1;
    }
    private void sendIt(View arg0, String destination) throws NullPointerException {
        _getLocation();     
        String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        try {
            destLatitude  = latSM(destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            destLongitude = lngSM(destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!exceptionRaised) {
            # the following just outputs the SMS message
            boolean success = mSender.sendSMSMessage("+16697219797",
            "{\"current\":"+'"'+longitude+","+latitude+"\""+",\"desired\":" +
                    '"'+destLatitude+","+destLongitude+"\",\"lang\":\""+language+"\"}");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Message " + (
            success ? "sent successfully" : "not sent - error"), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your device doesnt support it..Try testing it in a different device..

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to use a separate Geocoder for lat and lon, make one method that returns a LatLng object so that you only have to call `getFromLocationName()` one time.